# Existence of Non-Borel sets in models of "All sets measurable"

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

We know that the consistency of ZFC+"Exists an inaccessible cardinal" implies the consistency of ZF+DC+"All sets are Lebesgue measurable"; and DC proves the existence of non-Borel sets.

J. Truss proved that repeating Solovay's construction by collapsing any limit cardinal to be $\aleph_1$ we obtain a model of ZF+"All sets are Lebesgue measurable", and in that model DC holds if and only if we collapsed an inaccessible. If we collapsed a singular cardinal then the resulting model has the property that all sets are Borel.

> If we assume ZF+"All sets are Lebesgue measurable"+"There exists a non-Borel set", can we conclude that there is an inner model with an inaccessible cardinal?

---

Some clarifications:

1. When I say Borel sets, I mean elements of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets.
2. When I say Lebesgue sets, I mean elements of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by completing the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with respect to the null ideal.
3. As the Borel measure may fail to be $\sigma$-additive, we can as the following to complement the above question:

   > Assume that ZF+"All sets are Lebesgue measurable"+"The Borel measure is $\sigma$-additive", can we conclude that there is an inner model with an inaccessible cardinal?

   Now, taking the Borel and Lebesgue sets as defined above makes more sense.
4. The above leads to the next question:

   > If the Borel measure is *not* $\sigma$-additive, can we represent $\mathbb R$ as a countable union of null sets?

   (It is tempting to say immediately yes, but remember that countable unions of countable sets need not be countable anymore.)

Comment: Could you say what you mean exactly by "all sets are Lebesgue measurable" in a context without DC? After all, the theory of Lebesgue measure in ZF can seem to break down (imagine that the reals are a countable union of countable sets). 

Comment: While you're at it, could you say what you mean exactly by "Borel set"?  I assume that you mean a set in the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets, but, if you talk with enough set theorists, you *might* mean a set with a Borel code (i.e., a real that encodes how to build the set from open sets by iterated complementation and countable union).  The two meanings can differ in the absence of choice.

Comment: There is always a set without a Borel code: the set of all Borel codes $b$ which are not elements of the set coded by $b$. 

Comment: Incidentally, Asaf, I think you mean to raise the question, rather than beg it. http://begthequestion.info/

Comment: And by the way, it is a great question!

Comment: Joel - I salute your perseverance, but that horse bolted a long time ago.

Comment: In view of Joel’s example, the definition is still unclear to me. The set $I$ of all sets that can be covered for every $\epsilon>0$ by a countable sequence of open intervals whose lengths sum to $\epsilon$ is an ideal, but not ZF-provably a $\sigma$-ideal. Is the “null ideal” $I$, the $\sigma$-ideal generated by $I$, or something else?

Comment: Emil, I want to say "yes", but I feel that I am walking into a trap. Namely, this ideal can be everything. On the other hand, I feel that this is might be what I am looking for as an answer.

Comment: I also salute Joel's perseverance about "beg", but I'm not sure "raise" is the optimal replacement for it in this context. I think people raise questions, while facts, phenomena, and the like suggest questions, or lead to questions, or ....

Comment: Asaf, I probably didn’t make myself clear. I wasn’t asking for the truth value of the disjunction in my last question, but rather which of the three disjuncts holds.

Comment: Emil, I know you that. I wasn't 100% focused and just wrote a blurb of thought. I meant to say that I don't know what to answer exactly because it seems that the nontrivial failures of the null ideal to be $\sigma$-ideal might be a reasonable answer. Anyway, I tried to address this in the edit.

Comment: Hi Asaf. It definitely becomes relevant when studying this problem whether one is looking at codes or at sets, as the answers may be different, as Andreas mentioned. For example, though $\mathbb R$ may be a countable union of null sets, it is never itself null. This is also related to whether we want to look at the ideal or the $\sigma$-ideal of null sets. Nice questions!